# How do I fix unrecognized name: error when using is_incremental?

Tags: dbt

I'm working on making an dbt model incremental, but when calling `{% if is_incremental() %}` it fails to find the original column name: `Unrecognized name: date_consultation_scheduled_tz at [4:17]` However that column is indeed there because I can see it in the database and there are other models using that field, however anytime I call for incremental it breaks.

My original code looks like this:

```
{% set is_holiday_column = "check_holiday_region_" ~ region.lower()  %}

{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        tags=[ "fact_final_table"]
    )
}}
select
        client_id
        , time_to_call
        , consultation_scheduled_date
        , abs({{count_not_work_days('weekend', 'date_screened', 'consultation_scheduled_date')}})           as calc_time_to_call_weekday
        , abs({{count_not_work_days('holidays', 'date_screened', 'consultation_scheduled_date')}})          as calc_time_to_call_holidays 
from(
    select 
            patient_sword_id
            , date(date_screened_at)                                                                        as date_screened
            , date(date_consultation_scheduled_tz)                                                          as consultation_scheduled_date
            , abs(date_diff(date(date_screened), date(date_consultation_scheduled_tz), day))                as time_to_call
    from {{ref ('dimension_clients_table')}} 
    )
{% if is_incremental() %}
WHERE DATE(consultation_scheduled_date) >= DATE("{{ macro_incremental_max_date('consultation_scheduled_date') }}")
{% endif %}
```

I thought I had the where clause in the wrong place so I moved it inside the subquery

````
select
        client_id
        , time_to_call
        , consultation_scheduled_date
        , abs({{count_not_work_days('weekend', 'date_screened', 'consultation_scheduled_date')}})           as calc_time_to_call_weekday
        , abs({{count_not_work_days('holidays', 'date_screened', 'consultation_scheduled_date')}})          as calc_time_to_call_holidays 
from(
    select 
            client_id
            , date(date_screened_at)                                                                        as date_screened
            , date(date_consultation_scheduled_tz)                                                          as consultation_scheduled_date
            , abs(date_diff(date(date_screened), date(date_consultation_scheduled_tz), day))                as time_to_call
    from {{ref ('dimension_clients_table')}} 
    {% if is_incremental() %}
     WHERE DATE(consultation_scheduled_date) >= DATE("{{              macro_incremental_max_date('consultation_scheduled_date') }}")
{% endif %}
    )```

That still gave the same error.

From there I thought if I removed the subquery and focus on that snippet of code itself I would figure out what I had missed in there.


Still gives ```Unrecognized name: date_consultation_scheduled_tz at [4:17]```
````

Comment: Can you provide the compiled code? Looks like an SQL error to me